# Return the List<Student> from Elastic Search query result using Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I have been working with Elastic Search version 5.6.16 & Spring Boot. I want to perform the search on the basis of string .For that purpose i have write the following code.

**`Controller.java`**

```
public @ResponseBody String getItem(@RequestParam("data") String data) {
    QueryBuilder qb = QueryBuilders.queryStringQuery(data);
    SearchResponse searchResponse = client.prepareSearch("index")
      .setTypes("default").setQuery(qb).setSize(10).execute().actionGet();
    return  searchResponse;
}
```

this method is returning the **String**. But i want to get the result as `List <Student>`. Where the `Student` class is:

**`Student.java`**

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class Student {

    private int id;
    private int name;
}
```

> I am uploading the data of "student" on ES index. Please let me know how I could get the results from ES as List

Comment: Please share your mappings and your input query (data)

Comment: @AssaelAzran sir what did you mean from **mappings** ?. The data="John Doe" (let say). It is returning the document that has "John Doe" but I want to get as List<Student>.

Comment: Ok. find my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this change will help you to make a progress:

```
public @ResponseBody List<Student> getItem(@RequestParam("data") String data) {

    List<Student> records = new ArrayList<Student>(); 
    QueryBuilder qb = QueryBuilders.queryStringQuery(data);
    SearchResponse searchResponse = client.prepareSearch("index")
      .setTypes("default").setQuery(qb).setSize(10).execute().actionGet();
    SearchHit[] results = searchResponse.getHits().getHits();
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper()
    .configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
    for(SearchHit hit : results){

        String source = hit.getSourceAsString();
        Student s = objectMapper.readValue(source,Student.class);
        records.add(s);
    }
    return  records;
}
```

[objectMapper](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-object-mapper-tutorial)

Hope this helps

Comment: this is not working fine either. showing this error.
"Unrecognized field . not marked as ignorable (40 known "
Source: (StringReader); line: 1, column: 10] (through reference chain:

Comment: when we send a GetRequest and if the data string is available in the ES than it is failed. But if it is not present it is simply showing the empty

Comment: But where does it fail? do you get any data in **searchResponse** object?

Comment: yeah I get the required data in **searchResponse**

Comment: It looks like the objectmapper found unrecognized fields that are not part of Student class, i added configuration to objectmapper to ignore unrecognized field. see my answer.

Comment: this is now returning the object of students but all the values are null.